# On the meanings of the colors in Russian

Tags: значения, сленг

It is sometimes the case that one attributes a second meaning to the colors, in poetry or just slang. It might be that this association is language-dependent (perhaps an exception is *a* connotation of "green" as environmentally friendly). Please provide an example, and if possible, the reason for this association.

What are the most common meanings attributed to colors in Russian?

Comment: this is an immense topic,   and these relations depend not so much on nationality as on individuality and other things:> Well, black is the color of mourning, white is the color of a wedding ... Red is the color of the Reds, white is the color of Whites, "Green" is the color of those simply brigands ..:> or mb black :> https://youtu.be/e0ECy37ayUw?t=1745 
A lot of things we can write here ...:>

Comment: https://blog.cognifit.com/ru/психология-цвета-значение-цвета/   
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Язык_цветов#Символика   
https://f-gl.ru/геральдический-глоссарий/цвета-в-геральдике   
etc... 
"But this is not precisely"(c)
:>>

Comment: https://mgimo.ru/upload/iblock/df6/df66b41e6f203f67692e719e14f8239e.pdf

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, let me try:

- **Серый** — boring, mediocre; semi-legal ("серый рынок").
- **Красный** — (obsolete, but fully understandable nowadays by any native speaker), beautiful: "Красная площадь", "красна девица". Moreover, historically it is its first, original meaning, only later on did it become a color indication, displacing *червонный/червлённый*; may also mean strong or exaggerated as in "красное словцо".
- **Голубой** — male homosexual ("голубая" for lesbian is inappropriate); relaxed in "голубые грёзы"/"голубая нега" (something close to [dolce far niente](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dolce_far_niente)); (rapidly becoming historical) television in phrase "голубой экран"; (historical, not understandable nowadays) gendarmes, police in tzarist Russia, in phrase "голубые штаны", [check out also](http://folk-costume.com/goroxovyj-cvet/) *гороховое пальто*.
- **Розовый** — in phrases like "жизнь в розовых тонах" or "смотреть на мир сквозь розовые очки" means rose-colored, (unduly) optimistic. *Розовая* sometimes is used for indicating lesbianism, but, compared to *голубой* is used much more rarer.
- **Зелёный** — greenhorn ("ты ещё зелёный совсем, куда тебе"); environment-friendly, ecologic ("зелёные технологии"); apathy, cheerless as in "тоска зелёная (drowsy boredoom, depression)". One can also turn green from anger ("позеленеть от злости"). In the late Soviet time, the American dollars were called "зелень" (green stuff) or just "зеленые". "Зелёнка" in military slang means woodland or dense thickets (in everyday use just Brilliant Green dye).
- **Белый** — (noun) I hate to say it, but it is heroin; legal ("белый рынок", "белая зарплата"); "белая ворона" ironically, this can be translated as "black sheep". "Белая зависть" (white envy) means that you are glad for someone, but also regret that you aren't like him/her, as opposed to "черная зависть" (black envy) when you are angry that the other person has something that you don't.
- **Чёрный** — illegal ("чёрный рынок"); villainous ("чёрное дело ты задумал"); dreary ("на душе черным-черно").
- **Жёлтый** — in the phrase "жёлтая пресса", which is a calque of "[yellow press](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_journalism)"; there is also derivative adjective "желтушный" and noun "желтуха" ("Вся эта статья — чистая желтуха"). In the phrase "желторотый птенец", it means a very unexperienced person.
- **Фиолетово** (as an adverb, not an adjective) — used to indicate indifference: "Мне это абсолютно фиолетово".
- **Побагроветь** (verb, derivative from "багровый") — to get furious, to get pissed off ("Валерий Петрович побагровел от возмущения"). Cf. also  *сделаться белым*.
- **Серо-буро-малиновый** — colloquial description of a color that is hard to determine or that is a result of a strange medley of hues.

Political (ability to understand these depending on one's education and conversation context, although красные and белые are much more recognizable than others):

- **Красные** — communists.
- **Белые** — the White movement.
- **Коричневые** — fascists.

Also, an edit has been suggested to incorporate into this list the phrase *малиновый звон*, but be warned, this [has nothing to do](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD) with the color *малиновый*. Much rather, this is a phonetical coincidence, much like *Китай-город* is by no means related to China.

Comment: 1) does "Красная пресса" mean the press that focuses on delictive acts? (sorry if unrelated, but in my language it does) 2) why does blue mean homosexual and brown, fascist?

Comment: "красная пресса" most probably means communist (or wider - leftist) press. As for reasons, this link can help you - http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Красно-коричневые

Comment: @JorgeCampos as for gay, I guess it is pretty simple - blue is boys color.

Comment: @Jorge Campos no, "red press" in Russian can only mean Communist press.

Comment: Regarding brown, that is because the Nazi SA wore brown shirts in the 1930s.

Comment: I disagree about brown. I think it has no fashism connotations. The majority of people even don't know that it has been used as the uniform color in the 3rd Reich, I believe.

Comment: Also, "green" may mean "boring", as in тоска зеленая.

Comment: Also, "красное словцо" is not curse, it is exaggeration or joke.

Comment: @Olga, "после серых всегда приходят коричневые" is relatively well-know phrase, in political slang it is pretty common.

Comment: а можно использовать *Зелeный* так? *зеленая книжка* или ,,как  зелено"=какая скучно ?

Comment: @Olga there is special kind of political associations with colors. Reds=communists, whites=anti-communists, greens=islamists or ecologists or bandits in Russian civil war, oranges=pro-US revolutionaries. These associations are not hard-coded and can change depending on the context.

Comment: @Jorge Campos "зеленая книга" may either mean Quaran or the opus magnus of the former Libyan leader Muammar Kaddafi or something like this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Book_%28chemistry%29

Comment: @JorgeCampos,  no - "тоска зелёная" is strongly idiomatic, and in any other phrase green won't be associated with boredom.

Comment: красный/белый/зеленый were used to mark sides in Russian Civil War. Белый marks white race, Черный may mark either negroid race or modern inhabitants of Caucasus. 'Чёрный' often means illegal, like 'черный нал'(черная наличка), 'черный рынок'.

Comment: @Anixx About politics: but this meaning of the colors is not specific for Russian.

Comment: @Olga, you are wrong, if it is not specific (i.e. used not only in Russian), it does not mean that it is not a part of Russian language. "Зелёный" for indicating juvenile is not specific to Russian, though it is Russian.

Comment: @shabunc let's go to chat. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6334/on-the-meaning-of-the-colors

Comment: What about phrase: "ты что, красный что-ли"? :-)

Comment: Another word that looks like the name of a colour but can have nothing to do with the colour (like *малиновый* in *малиновый звон*) is *Серый*. It's when it is used as one of the familiar forms of the name *Сергей*.

Comment: "Olga about brown. I think it has no fashism connotations." - of course, it is. Absolutely. But of course all these things are context-sensitive and individually. :> 
the immense and stupid question, really. Many things here can be arqued and impugnable.

Comment: c.p, " why does ... and brown, fascist? – "  - it's, firstly,  historical thing. They (in NSDAP and their terrorists) weared brown shirts, they liked it, it was be their choise. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Штурмовые_отряды ; And they was named also "коричнерубашечники, коричневорубашечники". Also in Italy were  approximated  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Чернорубашечники; 

https://youtu.be/i-2FoCchImc - but the real color of IT more similar to a child shit :> ("цвет детской неожиданности", the our idiom. :>). 
It's also good vivid mental relation and assotiation about IT-a shit. :>

Comment: And, next, this color was fixed historically and politically to the fascists-at-all. It's already settled. In this - context. :>

Comment: "firstly, historical thing. " - and - the international. Thing. :>

Comment: "greens=islamists or ecologists or bandits" - Anixx ? "ecologists in Civil War" ? :))))))))))))) Just a bandits... :>
Oh, i suppose - you just mixed any different contexts... for islamists in Civil War (and for islamists at all) nobody say "green", just a bandit-basmuch...

Comment: shabunc, ""после серых всегда приходят коричневые" is relatively well-know phrase, in political slang it is pretty common" - this quote from the Strugatskys is correct - politically, but not linguistically-literary literally; "После серых всегда приходят чёрные".  But considering what i said above that чернорубашечники and коричневорубашечники are one and the same, the meaning is the same:>

Comment: c.p. " можно использовать Зелeный так? зеленая книжка или ,,как зелено"=какая скучно ? " - hah... :))) No, in general... :>>  "Зеленая книжечка генерала Бризака" :>>as the quotation... You may read "Bayazet" by Picul :) http://loveread.ec/view_global.php?id=15149

Comment: Also is "зелено вино" as archaic idiom, and "зеленый змий" - about alcohol :) exactly archaic "змИй", not a "змей" :)
https://youtu.be/odo6MTWmERs?t=50

Comment: "зеленые человечки" - about extraterrestrials. Or about alcoholic hallucinations, like as "допиться до чертиков". Зеленых. :> https://youtu.be/m0Cf-9TyAe0

"Красная Книга"  - international name of list of dying animal species... and you can meet this in conversations, as a metaphor... about smth/smbd rare and/or unfortunate -  "их в красную книгу заносить пора"... :>

Answer (score 9):

**Синий** - drunk. *Синяк* - drunkard.

Comment: Welcome to Russian.SE.  When formulating your answers, it is good to put more explanation than just one word. As you are adding relevant information, you can try to explain the origin and or relevance of this information (or cite a reference source).

Comment: Very rarely used form of `Зелёный` is `Junkie`. Used along with `Синий` (as `drunkard`) to describe preferences in consuming of things "which widen the consciousness".

Answer (score 5):

- **Серый** is also a policeman because of the uniform colour. It can be also a nick name for Sergey (Сергей) or a kind of pet name along with Серёжа.
- **Зеленые** - US$ (e.g. штука зеленых/зелени == 1000$)

Comment: +1 for зелёный, how could I forget. as for серый - серые шинели, well, not exactly about police.

Answer (score 2):

**Красный цвет**

1. имеющий окраску красного цвета - *красная кровь, красная роза.*
2. связанный с советским прошлым  - *красный воин, красная гвардия*.
3. обозначает красивый, яркий, нарядный, чаще употребляется в поэзии и в разговорной речи - *красна девица, «Попрыгунья Стрекоза лето красное пропела» (Крылов).*

Answer (score 0):

**Серый** is also meaning a wolf, **зеленый** - an unripe fruit.

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta! Usually we prefer longer and more elaborated answers on short answers. If you can improve your answer by adding detail, context, examples, and backing up with references, this would increase your answer's quality. Poor answers risk being down-voted and subsequently removed.